# HG-How to push existing source code to new created repository

Tags: mercurial

I created an empty hg repository, saying /tmp/repo/, using

```
                          hg init
```

At the same time, i have another directory: /opt/source, which contains a bunch of source codes.How can i push the source files under /opt/source to my new created /tmp/repo, using mercurial commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have source code in one directory and a "backup" repository, then both of your directories need to be a repository first (run `hg init` in both of them). To transfer files between repositories use `hg push` and `hg pull` (assuming you have **commited files** on one of these repos) like this:

`hg push /tmp/repo` (inside `/opt/source`)

or

`hg pull /opt/source` (inside `/tmp/repo`).